# r repeated measures output error (main effects shown twice, between subject shown as within)

Tags: r, anova

I am having trouble discerning the error strata output from a repeated measures anova in R, as they appear to be doing something funky. I have a repeated measures anova where each participant gets a score for two different roles and a score for two different valences (Role and Valence are dichotomous categorical within subjects factors), and I am including them in a model that has Gender as a between subjects factor (also dichotomous categorical).

**My model is as follows:**

```
summary(aov(data = data,
         score ~ Role * Valence * Gender + Error(Subject_ID / (Role*Valence)))
```

**The output looks unusual:**

```
 summary(aov(data = data,
+         score ~ Role * Valence * Gender + Error(Subject_ID / (Role*Valence))))
```

Error: Subject_ID

```
Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq
Gender  1 0.06647 0.06647
```

Error: Valence

```
        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
Valence  1  6.774   6.774
```

Error: Subject_ID:Role

```
     Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq
Role  1 0.04595 0.04595
```

Error: Subject_ID:Valence

```
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq
Valence:Gender  1 0.06981 0.06981
```

Error: Subject_ID:Role:Valence

```
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
Role:Valence  1  1.329   1.329
```

Error: Within

```
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Role                  1   0.00  0.0000   0.000 0.9986  
Gender                1   0.08  0.0781   0.382 0.5371  
Role:Valence          1   0.65  0.6457   3.159 0.0767
Role:Gender           1   0.04  0.0354   0.173 0.6777  
Valence:Gender        1   0.04  0.0443   0.217 0.6420  
Role:Valence:Gender   1   0.24  0.2447   1.197 0.2749  
Residuals           252  51.50  0.2044                 

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I don't understand why the F and P values only displayed for the within error strata, why my main effects are appearing twice (e.g., Role under within and Subject_ID:Role), or why my between subjects variable is showing up in the Within error strata. I'm not sure how to begin troubleshooting this, so any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've resolved the issue on my own, but am going to leave this post up in case someone encounters a similar issue. My repeated measure (Subject_ID) was coded as integers. Turns out it needs to be a character or factor. I paste0'd "Subject" in front of each value (e.g., 27 became Subject27), reran the model, and the output was as expected. Cheers.